# Виртуальная наследственность классов

Tags: c++

Приветствую, у меня вопрос. По поводу классов:

```C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
   public:
    void f() {
        cout << "It's A" << endl;
             }
};
class B: virtual public A {
public:
    void f()
    {
        cout << "It' s B" << endl;
    }
};
class C: virtual public A {
public:
    void f()
    {
        cout << "It's C" << endl;
    }
};
class D: public C
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        cout << "It's D" << endl;
    }
};
class E: public C {
public:
    void f()
    {
        cout << "It's E" << endl;
    }
};
class F:  public C {};

int main ()
{
    F JESUS;
    JESUS.f();
}
```

В итоге выводит "It's C"

Вопрос по поводу класса "F". Т.к. у меня всё "ссылается" к классу "A", из-за этого мы можем использовать только один производный класс (для "F", разумеется, но я могу написать любой класс, кроме B). И если мы заиспользуем больше производных классов, то получим ошибка о "неявности". Вроде так... Если я не прав, то как реализовать класс "F"?

Вопрос, правильно ли я рассуждаю?

**Вот таблица, по которой я руководствовался:**
[image: таблица]

Comment: Я не понимаю, что значит: можем использовать только один производный класс?... И почему будет ошибкой использование многих производных классов?..

Comment: Мне одному вопрос совершенно непонятен?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, насколько я понял, т.к. все классы "идут" к A, поэтому будет ошибка "неявного" вызова f().

Comment: @Harry, уффф, тогда спрошу так): я правильно заходил или нет?

Comment: Каждый обьект будет вызывать  f()  своего класса, если там она есть,  в обратном случаи будет вызывать ся функция непосредственного базового класса, так дальше по иерархии. Виртуальность базового  класса для данного примера не имеет значения... Вы правильно вызываете и можете вызвать эту функцию через обьект любого класса

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ага..... спасибо, именно это я и хотел узнать.

Comment: я рад, что смог быть полезен...